# params and problems with if statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create 3 links:

- *Popularne* - `/`
- *Nowe* - `/?order=1`
- *Najlepsze* - `/?order=2`

Below code creates these links. Now, depends on `params[:order]` I want set this link to `class="active"`. I setup `<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>` and when I click for example *Nowe* it shows me order: '1' but looks like this if statement with `params[:order]` doesn't work, and it is not generating `class="active"`. It works only for *Popularne*. Any idea where is a problem? Looks like it's `params[:order]`.

```
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><%= !params[:order] ? link_to("Popularne",{},:class=>"active"):link_to("Popularne")%></li>
    <li><%= params[:order] == 1 ? link_to("Nowe",:order=>1,:class=>"active"):link_to("Nowe",:order=>1)%></li>
    <li><%= params[:order] == 2 ? link_to("Najlepsze",:order=>2,:class=>"active"):link_to("Najlepsze",:order=>2)%></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: It seems that params[:order] is a String rather that Fixnum.

Comment: You were right, just added == "1" and =="2", and brackets for :order=> 1. Thanks.